# How should we define "locally small"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory

Let U be a Grothendieck universe, and U<sup>+</sup> its successor universe (assume Grothendieck's universe axiom).

Everybody agrees that a U-small category is a category whose sets of objects and morphisms are both elements of U.  For the "next larger size" of categories which are not necessarily even locally small, call them just U-categories, there are two possible definitions:

- a category whose set of objects and Hom-sets are all subsets of U;
- a category whose set of objects and Hom-sets are all elements of U<sup>+</sup> (U<sup>+</sup>-small categories).

I quite prefer the second notion, so that the category of U-categories is cartesian closed and we can form localizations.  This is the usage of Dwyer-Hirschhorn-Kan-Smith, "Homotopy Limit Functors on Model Categories and Homotopical Categories".  I think the first more closely corresponds to non-Grothendieck universe-based treatments of category theory using sets and classes, but I might be wrong about that.

For U-locally small categories there are again two possible definitions:

- a category whose set of objects is a subset of U and whose Hom-sets are elements of U,
- a category whose set of objects is an element of U<sup>+</sup> and whose Hom-sets are elements of U.

I don't see a strong reason to prefer one over the other, except that the second is more parallel with my preference for U-categories.  DHKS uses the first.  As an example of the difference between them, if I have a U-locally small category C, I can form the category (poset) of full subcategories of C; this is U-locally small under the second definition, but not the first.  Is this a good thing or a bad thing?  Or are there no theorems I would care about that are affected by this difference?  Does anyone have an opinion about these two definitions?

Comment: In the definition of U-locally small, shouldn't it be "Hom-sets" instead of "set of morphisms"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that the first notion of U-category corresponds more
closely to non-Grothendieck-universe-based treatments, e.g. using NBG
or MK set-class theory.  To be precise, if U is a universe, defining
"set" to mean "element of U" and "class" to mean "subset of U" gives a
model of MK set-class theory (and hence also NBG, which is weaker than
MK).  A comparison of the relationships between different set-theoretic
treatments of large categories can be found in my expository paper
"[Set theory for category theory](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279)."

Here is an example of one theorem that can (maybe) tell the difference
between the two notions of U-locally-small categories.  Let C be a
U-category whose hom-sets are in U (i.e. a "U-locally-small category"
by your second definition).  Then C has a Yoneda embedding C →
[Cº,Set] where Set is the U-category of U-small sets.  Note that
[Cº,Set] is only a U-category by your second definition (i.e. a
U⁺-small category).  We say that C is **lex-total** if this Yoneda
embedding has a left adjoint which preserves finite limits.  It is a
theorem of Freyd, which can be found in Ross Street's paper "Notions
of topos," that if C is lex-total *and* also U-locally-small according
to your *first* definition (its set of objects is a subset of U), then C
is a Grothendieck topos (i.e. the category of U-small sheaves on some
U-small site).  The converse is not hard to prove, so this gives a
characterization of Grothendieck toposes.  As far as I know, it is
unknown whether there can be lex-total U-categories with very large
object sets that are not Grothendieck toposes.

I would personally be inclined to use your second definition of
"U-locally small," because as you say it matches your preferred
definition of large category relative to U (which I would prefer to
just call a "U⁺-small category", since its definition makes no reference
to U), and also because the term "U-locally small" sounds as if it
only imposes a smallness condition locally.  Street uses "moderate"
for a category with at most a U-small set of isomorphism classes of
objects, so if one wants to state a theorem (such as the above) about
U-locally-small categories according to your first definition, one can
instead say "U-locally-small and U-moderate."

Comment: I prefer the second definition too, but since most texts use something like the first definition, I just wanted to check that there wasn't some subtle reason that theorems could be affected by the difference.