# Logical problems in category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set theory for category theory beginners](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6423/set-theory-for-category-theory-beginners)

It is frustrating to hear people speak of Yoneda embedding, category of all categories/functors, n-categories, infinity categories and all that jargon, without giving proper logical justifications.

I learned category theory from N. Jacobson, Basic Algebra - II. The justification given therein, that one uses the Godel-Bernays distinction of sets and classes, simply does not work for the above cases.

This is really frustrating. How do people deal with it? It seems many times it is skipped simply, giving the impression that it is too unimportant to be dealt with.

How did then the  more foundational guys, for instance, Grothendieck deal with it? What are the "universes" one hears from time to time?

Comment: This question seems closely related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6423/set-theory-for-category-theory-beginners

Comment: Yes it could be considered potentially offensive. I have edited. 

Comment: The examples of category of all categories, category of all functors, Yoneda embedding, etc, I have mentioned, does not make sense within either the Zermelo-Fraenkel, or Godel-Bernays set theories, which are the ones mentioned in the book I have referred to. I am sorry; I wanted the question to be short; so I gave the book reference and gave examples without detailed arguments of why they don't work out. But it is really easy to see, if you just look at the definitions, etc. 

Comment: I'm closing it as a duplicate because it looks like the answers there address the underlying question, which seems to be "what are the set-theoretic underpinnings of category theory?" In general, I would keep two substantially different versions of the same question open, but this is just too imprecise. I feel like it's mostly a tirade without any backup. To quote Ilya's answer, "perhaps you could provide logical inconsistencies in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory?" As usual, if the question is edited into shape, or if enough people want it, I (or somebody else) will reopen it.

Comment: Let me explain how I think this could be made into a good question. Make it specific. Rather than saying, *"nobody ever gives logical justification for anything,"* say, *"Here's a specific thing that Lurie does that doesn't look justified to me. I've read this and that about Grothendieck universes, which are supposed to resolve the problem, but it seems to me that isn't enough because of X."* Even better, ask, *"Is X (same X as before) true?"* and give all that stuff as motivation and background for why you want to know if X is true.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. The other question was mainly about references, and the answers for the most part pointed at recommended texts. The current question is about how one can formalize category theory within set theory, which is a different topic. The question of what are the set-theoretic underpinnings of category theory is a central foundational concern, and I would be interested to read some well-thought out answers here. I vote to re-open.

Comment: @Joel: I don't understand your objection. It seems to me that the *contents* of those references in the answers to the other question are the well thought-out answers you're looking for.

Comment:  The other question was styled like being asked by a beginner in category theory. This one is asked by a person who used bits and pieces of categories, but is dissatisfied with what he learned as foundational justifications, when faced with the next level of the usage, for example usage in functorial algebraic geometry. There is a difference between the two. Well, a few answers to this question might have appeared as answers to that earlier question 

Comment: The Yoneda embedding is dealt with at the beginning of SGA IV.

Comment: @Anton: Giving a reference list is quite different than explaining a mathematical idea. After all, we wouldn't want to close the MO and replace the main page with a list of about twenty textbooks, even if the contents of those textbooks contained the answers to nearly all our questions here. 

Comment: @Anweshi: please read at least the first eight sections of Mike Shulman's paper linked to from his answer to the other question, and if you have any *specific* questions after reading it, feel free to ask them!

Comment: I agree that the question could be better phrased, but I think it is a very relevant one (i.e., I would like to see some more answers to it!) and have voted to reopen. The bottom line is that I have seen plenty of people trying to use categorical constructions that, *a priori*, didn't make set theoretic sense.  (These people were, like most mathematicians/students who use categorical constructions, not category theorists.  I can well believe that the category theorists know what they are doing far better than the rest of us)...

Comment: As a graduate student, I gave lectures on etale cohomology.  From the books that I was using (not SGA!), some constructions required modifications by me to be set-theoretically correct.  It was not obvious to everyone in the audience why I was going to the additional trouble.  I remember having to argue for the point that it didn't make sense to take (something like) the direct sum of Z over all abelian groups.  This was at Harvard.  Summary: some people simply ignore set-theoretic difficulties, which makes it harder for the rest of us to learn how to correctly overcome them.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: category theorists often elide the extra annotations when employing [typical ambiguity](http://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/Ambiguity.pdf) or [universe polymorphism](http://lists.seas.upenn.edu/pipermail/types-list/2008/001256.html).  Proof theorists demand that these annotations be provided, and study how they behave.

If you want to be pedantic, then you have to annotate all instances of "category of sets" or "category of categories" with the additional word "small".  Then the objects of the category of small sets do not form a small set, and the category of small categories is not a small category.

The next step is to replace "small" with an arbitrary natural number, where the objects of the "category of 0-small sets" form a 1-small set.  Often, when fully annotated, it turns out that a proof will work for any value of "N" (where all the references to Set or Cat in the proof involve "offsets" from that N, such as "(N+3)-small sets").  Proofs which are parametric in this N (or some sequence N,M,... with inequality constraints between them) are called universe-polymorphic proofs, and are quite similar to a phenomenon in Principia Mathematica called typical ambiguity (although PM asserted a staggeringly powerful axiom about typical ambiguity without any sort of formal justification).  You can re-apply these proofs at arbitrary levels in the transfinite hierarchy of universes, and they still hold.

That said, nobody has yet proven that a category of ALL categories (of every "smallness") cannot exist in the way that Russell proved that a set of all sets cannot exist.  However, there is some evidence that you would have to omit certain axioms that might seem to be "obvious" at first glance.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are just reading the wrong books.  The most common solution to these problems is indeed [Grothendieck universes](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe).  Really, these issues are not that big a deal, not because they are logically unimportant, but because there are well-understood ways of dealing with them, which generally are extremely effective, and so it's not worth saying more than "small", "large", "very large", etc.—to do so would be distracting.  (You can probably find many such informal uses of language in other fields as well.)

Comment: I don't know if they're always effective. The collection of all semigroupoid homomorphisms themselves form a semigroupoid (under composition), and one cannot state this fact -- even using universes. It is disturbing to have a proposition be neither true nor false but simply arbitrarily excluded from consideration like that.

Comment: I don't know what a semigroupiod is, but why should one be any more able to state that fact than "the collection of all sets is a set", and what's wrong with instead stating the equivalent of "the collection of all U-sets is a V-set, where U and V are Grothendieck universes with U in V"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroupoid

Sets have vastly more structure than semigroupoids.  For example, the category of sets is cartesian closed (a fact which is used in the proof of Russell's paradox) while the category of semigroupoids is not.

Comment: We must be having some terminological misunderstanding, because that article implies that the collection of all semigroupoids doesn't form a semigroupoids, because a semigroupoid has a *set* of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Every question asked can be divided into two parts: what is known, and what is asked.

I think your question's "what is known" part is by no means universally agreed. It's *not* frustrating to hear people talk about categories or $\infty$-categories anymore than hear people talk about sets.

Yes, when you talk about sets, sometimes you can make mistake if you consider "the set of all sets", but if you're using set theory only to teach algebraic topology, you chances of making such a mistake while proving any interesting theorem aren't big. What's the reason the same doesn't apply here?

Therefore, I do not think it's possible to answer your "what is asked" part.

If you're unconvinced, perhaps you could provide logical inconsistencies in Lurie's [Higher Topos Theory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf)? (This is what I read for $\infty$-categories)